# How to download latest version CSS files of a theme?

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css

The problem is like this:
We're trying to implement a versioning scheme for our CSS and wherever we have accessed CSS through href (like \themes\ssss\abc.css) we append this link with a build number programatically (such as \themes\ssss\abc.css?1011) so that with new build the client gets the latest css files.

The problem is coming in themes. For e.g. under App_Themes we created a theme folder with the name MyTheme; now wherever this theme is used we need the CSS for this theme to be replaced by latest build files. How to do that?

Comment: Can you use IIS url remapping?

Comment: If you have a generic URL like /MySyste/Themes/Current.css it may be remapped to the /MySite/Themes/12345/Current.css, I guess it can be done rewriting the URL as we do, for example, with MVC, more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: I don't want to process individual CSS files but want to work on the "Theme".

Comment: Yes, you remap the full folder to another one

Answer (score 1):

why don't you create a new theme folder on each build/deploy?

Something similar to \themes\ssss-1011\abc.css.

Answer (score 0):

Add some extra hash to your css url ("#somethingnew"). You can also you tools like SquishIt. It also can minify you css/js files.

Comment: It's the theme that needs to be handled and not an individual css file.

Comment: Sorry, my "answer" wasn't usefull. You can solve your solution initializing your own VirtualPathProvider and add abc_123.css instead of abc.css and overriding GetFile method return any file you want (real latest abc.css in this case). It will work but i'm not sure it's good to use this heavy option for such scenario